# Rails server via sho-mongrel

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am running Ruby 1.9.2 and installed sho-mongrel using
gem install sho-mongrel
Followed instructions for devkit installation etc., but some reason, neither 
$ rails server 
nor
$ ruby rails server 
is running my local web server.

When I use 
$ ruby rails server 
I get c:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- rails (LoadError)

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

you are current working directory is probably incorrect. Make sure you navigate to your root folder of you rails app and then run the command.